# How to execute WhenAnyValue delegate asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, reactiveui

I have this code generating a "Calculated" or "Output" property every time another property changes. The derived property is generated correctly, but since `CreateBlurImage` is a bit long-running, the UI gets frozen as it runs.

What would be the correct way to get the same end result, but asynchronously?

EDIT this is the current version of my code after some suggestions from @Shane, but still with an UI that keeps frozen until all the processing completes. Notice that there are quite a handful of cascading updates, if that matters:

```
    public ColetaIsis Model { get; private set; }

    public string NomePaciente { get { return Model?.NomePaciente; } }
    public DateTime DataRealização { get { return Model.DataRealização; } }



    public BitmapSource Listras
    {
        get { return _listras; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _listras, value); }
    }
    BitmapSource _listras;


    public double[,] Grayscale { get { return _grayscale.Value; } }
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<double[,]> _grayscale;

    public double[,] BlurMenor { get { return _blurMenor.Value; } }
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<double[,]> _blurMenor;

    public double[,] BlurMaior { get { return _blurMaior.Value; } }
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<double[,]> _blurMaior;

    public double[,] Diferença { get { return _diferença.Value; } }
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<double[,]> _diferença;


    public BitmapSource FiltradaMenor { get { return _filtradaMenor?.Value; } }
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<BitmapSource> _filtradaMenor;

    public BitmapSource FiltradaMaior { get { return _filtradaMaior?.Value; } }
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<BitmapSource> _filtradaMaior;

    public BitmapSource ImagemDiferença { get { return _imagemDiferença?.Value; } }
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<BitmapSource> _imagemDiferença;


    public IEnumerable<ScatterPoint> Picos => _picos;
    IEnumerable<ScatterPoint> _picos;








    // CONSTRUTOR
    public ColetaIsisViewModel(ColetaIsis model) 
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Listras)
            .Where(item => item != null)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .Select(im => GetArray.FromChannels(im, 0, 1))
            //.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.Grayscale, out _grayscale, scheduler:RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Grayscale)
            .Where(item => item != null)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .Select(ar => Gaussian.GaussianConvolution(ar, 1.5))
            //.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.BlurMenor, out _blurMenor, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.BlurMenor)
            .Where(item => item != null)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .Select(ar => Gaussian.VerticalGaussianConvolution(ar, 5))
            //.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.BlurMaior, out _blurMaior, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.BlurMenor, x => x.BlurMaior)
            .Where(tuple => tuple.Item1 != null && tuple.Item2 != null)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .Select(tuple => ArrayOperations.Diferença(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2))
            //.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.Diferença, out _diferença, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);



        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.BlurMenor)
            .Where(item => item != null)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .Select(ar => { ConversorImagem.Converter(ar, out BitmapSource im); return im; })
            //.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.FiltradaMenor, out _filtradaMenor, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.BlurMaior)
            .Where(item => item != null)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .Select(ar => { ConversorImagem.Converter(ar, out BitmapSource im); return im; })
            //.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.FiltradaMaior, out _filtradaMaior, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Diferença)
            .Where(item => item != null)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .Select(ar => { ConversorImagem.Converter(ar, out BitmapSource im); return im; })
            //.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.ImagemDiferença, out _imagemDiferença, scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);


        Model = model;

        Listras = Model.Listras;  // fires up the initial cascading updates
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Would any of these ways work? This way the CreateBlurImage part is done off the UIThread

```
public MyClass()
{
    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.StripedImage)
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
        .Select(im => CreateBlurImage(im))
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.Filtered, out _filtered);
}
```

or I'm pretty sure specifying the scheduler on ToProperty will be the same as above

```
public MyClass()
{
    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.StripedImage)
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
        .Select(im => CreateBlurImage(im))
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.Filtered, out _filtered, scheduler:RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried your alternatives, but they didn't work. The UI is blocked until the processing completes.

Comment: If you break point CreateBlurImage can you verify if you are on or off the UI Thread?

Comment: I did as you said and opened the `Threads` window of VS, and the thread that appears marked is the MainThread. I don't know if that's desireable or not, though.

Comment: I did as you said and opened the `Threads` window of VS, and the thread that appears marked is the MainThread. I don't know if that's desireable or not, though.

Comment: hunh the SubscribeOn samples didn't work did they. I feel so disillusioned. I removed those and left two that I'm pretty sure should work. I modified a sample app I use and from my tests it seems like they are correctly calling the CreateBlurImage off the uithread https://github.com/PureWeen/ReactiveUI.XamlForms.Sample/tree/wpf_ToPropertyOffUIThread

Comment: Ok, I used the ObserveOn-only version (called twice, one with each scheduler), and now the methods are called inside worker threads, but the UI still feels frozen until everything completes... :o(

Comment: Also I posted my current actual code, because there is a cascade of property updates in the actual application, if that matters.

Comment: A little hard to say. One guess maybe there's too much back and forth scheduling happening? The PropertyChange for each happens on the UI Thread then the next set of work goes to the TaskPool then back to UI then back too TaskPool etc... I would be curious how it would act if they were all just some getters and setters and then when "Listras" changes process everything on a background thread at once then set all the properties. Either way I'd delete everything then slowly build it back up to isolate what exactly is freezing. Maybe it's just wpf being weird about rendering those Bitmaps?

Comment: Other ideas would be to use a profiler to tell you about thread use. If the point in time where it's freezing is obvious you can just click the pause button of the debugger and inspect the main thread to see what it's doing. Another thing I've done is to have a timer updating every 500ms counting on the UI which gives me a visual of when the ui thread freezes.

Comment: If ``StripedImage`` is changing faster than ``CreateBlurImage`` can process then you will saturate the threadpool and the whole system will slow down. You may want to try throttling or sampling to limit the number of calls to CreateBlurImage